# Handlebars - update template without re-rendering DOM

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

Here is an interesting problem. I have template like this.

```
<script id="temp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 1  <input type="text" value="{{val1}}"/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 2  <input type="text" value="{{val2}}"/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 3  <input type="text" value="{{val3}}"/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 4  <input type="text" value="{{val4}}"/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 5  <input type="text" value="{{val5}}"/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label>Label 6  <input type="text" value="{{val6}}"/></label>
    </div>
    ....
    .... </script>
```

My template is pretty big. As i have shown above it has lot of inputs and i have included almost 10 [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in my template. First time it is ok to compile and add dom like this.

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#temp').html());
$('body').append(t(values);
```

but it is not good to re-render this entire template when i need to update only input and datetime pickers value. So i need to do something like below, which should update values alone.

> t(valueChanged);
>   OR
>   t('refresh', valueChanged);

Is there a way to do this? This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DRF6/2/) may help you.

Comment: did you consider replacing this big template with a CollectionView? it seems like it will require minimal code using Marionette

Comment: no. i haven't used Marionette yet. let me check it.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just access the DOM elements directly and patch things up by hand?

Comment: @muistooshort yes i'm doing this now. But i missed Handlebar awesomeness here. If handlebars has something like refresh, that would be terrifically awesome.

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to build that yourself. Handlebars is intentionally simple.

Comment: Yes. instead of adding these kind of functionalities into Ember, they should kept these logics in Handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

You need a template like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-item">
    <label> <%= data.label %>  <input type="text" value="<%= data.val %>"/></label>
</script>
```

Then use a backbone view like this:

```
  var app = app || {};

  // Item View
  // --------------
  app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'entry',

    template: _.template( $('#list-item').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);  
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html( this.template( {data : this.model.attributes} ) );
      return this;
    },

    clear: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    }
  });
```

Then use a collection to create/update a list of items.